# Writing to CSV without tokenizing words into letters

Tags: python, csv

So, I want to take the keys from the dictionary "data" [see code below] and write to a csv file a row of headers, so I'll have two columns, "name" and "language." Then I want to have four rows, the first being "Dave,Python", the second "Dennis,C" and so on. Should look like:

> name,language
> Dave,Python
> Dennis,C
> Peter,Java
> Jess,Python

Code:

```
data = {
    'name': ['Dave', 'Dennis', 'Peter', 'Jess'],
    'language': ['Python', 'C', 'Java', 'Python']
}

with open("dump.csv", mode="w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(data.keys())
    for n, l in zip(data["name"], data["language"]):
        writer.writerow(f'{n}{l}')
```

Here's what I'm actually getting:

> name,language
> D,a,v,e,P,y,t,h,o,n
> D,e,n,n,i,s,C
> P,e,t,e,r,J,a,v,a
> J,e,s,s,P,y,t,h,o,n

I'm pretty sure this is happening because strings are indexed in Python and my for n, l [etc.] line is somehow iterating over each index of the strings, but I don't know why it's happening or what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, strings are just arrays of characters. Meanwhile, `writerow()` expects an array of values to be turned into a row of fields. Instead, you're passing it a string you've combined together which results in each character being interpreted as a field.

You could either recombine `n` and `l` back into an array

```
writer.writerow([n, l])
```

Or simply don't bother destructuring the enumerated value from the `zip()` operation.

```
for row in zip(data["name"], data["language"]):
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Just to extend: Strings and lists (`[]` is called list in puthon) are iterable, as are tuples, sets etc. So, other iterables would have worked similarly. That strings and lists are arrays underneath is not important.

Answer (score 0):

`.writerow()` takes an iterable as an argument and writes all the parts as separate values to the csv.

You're giving it a string (`f'{n}{l}'`) and that's an iterable of characters, which explains the output you get.

You should do this instead:

```
        writer.writerow([n, l])
```

That gives it a list of strings, writing each string to its own position, without breaking it up.

Answer (score 0):

[Overkill] If you do not mind to add a (unnecessary) package, Pandas can ease the task.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'name': ['Dave', 'Dennis', 'Peter', 'Jess'],
    'language': ['Python', 'C', 'Java', 'Python']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("dump.csv", index=False)
```